# Meteor Application hosted in Azure using Accounts package causes mongodb connection error

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

The Meteor Accounts package triggers an interval to expire session tokens.
I am not sold this is an Azure thing, maybe it is.

source / accounts-base.js https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/f9f94e21d10676aaa4a8a6809cb3bbc2fa60f536/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L53

specifically this call fails, every ten minutes, from the source, that is every call fails: 
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/f9f94e21d10676aaa4a8a6809cb3bbc2fa60f536/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L1173

stack trace:
Exception in setInterval callback: Error: failed to connect to [x.x.x.x:27017] at Object.Future.wait (D:\home\site\wwwroot\programs\server\node_modules\fibers\future.js:398:15) at MongoConnection. (packages/meteor/helpers.js:119:1) at MongoConnection.(anonymous function) [as update] (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:736:49) at [object Object].update (packages/mongo/collection.js:568:29) at AccountsServer.Ap._expireTokens (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1092:14) at packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1130:14 at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1) at packages/meteor/timers.js:6:1 at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:110:1) - - - - - at [object Object]. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\programs\server\npm\node_modules\meteor\npm-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:556:74) at [object Object].emit (events.js:106:17) at [object Object]. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\programs\server\npm\node_modules\meteor\npm-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:156:15) at [object Object].emit (events.js:98:17) at Socket. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\programs\server\npm\node_modules\meteor\npm-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection.js:534:10) at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17) at net.js:441:14 at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)

1. is this bad?
2. what happens to the server when this issue occurs?
3. how do I fix it?

We are running Meteor 1.4, node 4.4.7 and mongo db 3.2.1

the connection string looks like this:
mongodb://me:shhh@x.x.x.x:27017/app?autoReconnect=true&connectTimeoutMS=60000&socketTimeoutMS=60000

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so looks like the issue was resolved by adding the above connection string details: &connectTimeoutMS=60000&socketTimeoutMS=60000